# search engine in asp classic

Tags: asp-classic, search-engine

I already try a search engine script like below:

```
<HTML><BODY>
<B>Search Results for <%=Request("SearchText")%></B><BR>

<%
Const fsoForReading = 1

Dim strSearchText
strSearchText = Request("SearchText")

''# Now, we want to search all of the files
Dim objFSO
Set objFSO = Server.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")


Dim objFolder
Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(Server.MapPath("/"))

Dim objFile, objTextStream, strFileContents, bolFileFound
bolFileFound = False

For Each objFile in objFolder.Files
  If Response.IsClientConnected then
    Set objTextStream = objFSO.OpenTextFile(objFile.Path,fsoForReading)

    strFileContents = objTextStream.ReadAll

    If InStr(1,strFileContents,strSearchText,1) then
       Response.Write "<LI><A HREF=""/" & objFile.Name & _
                      """>" & objFile.Name & "</A><BR>"

       bolFileFound = True
    End If

    objTextStream.Close
  End If
Next

if Not bolFileFound then Response.Write "No matches found..."

Set objTextStream = Nothing
Set objFolder = Nothing
Set objFSO = Nothing
%>
</BODY></HTML>
```

the output will show only the name of file, what i want is the title of the file.
my question is, how to get the string between  in order to show up for the result? or is there any other script related to search engine in asp classic?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I get what you mean, but if you intend on grabbing the file name without the path nor extension, here's a snippet I use:

```vb
Public Function GetFileName(flname As String) As String
'From: http://www.freevbcode.com/ShowCode.asp?ID=1638
'By:   Maria Rapini

    'Get the filename without the path or extension.
    'Input Values:
    '   flname - path and filename of file.
    'Return Value:
    '   GetFileName - name of file without the extension.

    Dim posn As Integer, i As Integer
    Dim fName As String

    posn = 0
    'find the position of the last "\" character in filename
    For i = 1 To Len(flname)
        If (Mid(flname, i, 1) = "\") Then posn = i
    Next i

    'get filename without path
    fName = Right(flname, Len(flname) - posn)

    'get filename without extension
    posn = InStr(fName, ".")
        If posn <> 0 Then
            fName = Left(fName, posn - 1)
        End If
    GetFileName = fName
End Function
```